# Unable to fetch the result from the search query in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a Wordpress plugin in which i have filled some dummy data inside the database.Also I have created a admin_menu page in the dashboard and now I am trying to fetch the data based on the query. With the single query of (SELECT * from TABLENAME) , its giving the results,but whenever I am trying to send the query its showing blank screen with this issue :**Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.** and I am the Admin too.

Please have a look at the code:

```
<?php 

global $wpdb , $table_prefix;
    $wp_emp = $table_prefix."emp";

    if(isset($_GET['my_search_term'])){

        if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
            $q = "SELECT * FROM `$wp_emp` WHERE `Name` LIKE '%" . $_GET["my_search_term"] . "%';";
            // Rest of your code...
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, you don't have permission to perform this search.";
        }
      
    }
    else{
        $q= "SELECT * FROM `$wp_emp`";
    }

   
    $results = $wpdb ->get_results($q);
   
    
    // print_r($results);

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>My plugin Page</h1>
        <div>
            <form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=my-submenu1'); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="my_plugin_page" />
                <input type="text" name="my_search_term" value="my_plugin_page" />
                <input type="submit" value="search" name="search" />
            </form>
        </div>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $result->Id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result->Name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result->Age; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
    




?>
```

Comment: Please be warned that your  query  is widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: I see the form action sends the user to a specific URL. What happens if instead of submitting the form, you open that URL directly?

Comment: Your form action creation there should result in something like `somepath/admin.php?page=my-submenu1` - but the hidden input field of the name `page` will overwrite that query string parameter, so submitting the form will result in a URL like `somepath/admin.php?page=my_plugin_page&my_search_term=...&search=search` - not sure if that was intentional? Or maybe the cause of the problem to begin with?